# Posting PHPBB Forum Thread/Post info in a website

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpbb

I am trying to extract, say, the latest/most recent 5 threads in the X section of my Forums and have it 'posted' on my website with a link so the viewers can go directly to the thread instead of having to browse the forum or what not.

I've seen and read some tutorials online but...in all honesty, phpbb seems like a mess to me.

All help appreciated
G.Campos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have access to the forum' db, you might want to try some phpbb3 portal, such as [this one](http://www.phpbb3portal.com).

However, if you do have access to the mysql(?) db, you might want to give a shot for a `SELECT` sentence, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM phpbb_posts WHERE forum_id = X ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT Y";
```

Change that 'X' to the forum id that you want to dump from, and the 'Y' to the post_time limit you want to stop dumping; having in mind that you will be facing with `strtotime` times, such as `1290886590`.

Then, execute the query and fetch the result (`mysql_fetch_array`) for formatting it on a table or whatever you want. Play with the `post_subject` and other columns for a nice output. Good luck.

Edit: You have a pretty extensive tutorial on the phpbb page, [here](http://blog.phpbb.com/2009/11/09/how-to-display-posts-and-topics-on-external-pages/). Give it a look.